# Opentdb weird characters

Tags: http, flutter, dart, request, character

I am making a trivia game in flutter with the opentdb API. But when I get the data from the API there are random characters between the words like " &quot " or " # 039 ". I don't know why they are there and even if I enter the link in the browser, the weird characters are there. Now I would like to know if I am doing something wrong or if there's a problem with the opentdb API. This is the opentdb link I'm using: https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20

This is the scrip I use to sort the data:

```
class Quiz {
  int responseCode;
  List<Results> results;

  Quiz({this.responseCode, this.results});

  Quiz.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    responseCode = json['response_code'];
    if (json['results'] != null) {
      results = new List<Results>();
      json['results'].forEach((v) {
        results.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['response_code'] = this.responseCode;
    if (this.results != null) {
      data['results'] = this.results.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Results {
  String category;
  String type;
  String difficulty;
  String question;
  String correctAnswer;
  List<String> allAnswers;

  Results(
      {this.category,
      this.type,
      this.difficulty,
      this.question,
      this.correctAnswer,
      this.allAnswers});

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    category = json['category'];
    type = json['type'];
    difficulty = json['difficulty'];
    question = json['question'];
    correctAnswer = json['correct_answer'];
    allAnswers = json['incorrect_answers'].cast<String>();
    allAnswers.add(correctAnswer);
    allAnswers.shuffle();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['difficulty'] = this.difficulty;
    data['question'] = this.question;
    data['correct_answer'] = this.correctAnswer;
    data['incorrect_answers'] = this.allAnswers;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And this is my main script:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:trivia_test/quiz.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.white),

    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Quiz quiz;
  List<Results> results;

  Future<void> fetchQuestions()async{
    var res = await http.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20");
    var decRes = json.decode(res.body);
    print(decRes);
    quiz = Quiz.fromJson(decRes);
    results = quiz.results;
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Quiz App", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'product_sans'),),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: fetchQuestions,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future:  fetchQuestions(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            switch(snapshot.connectionState){
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Text("Press button to start.");
              case ConnectionState.active:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if(snapshot.hasError) return errorData(snapshot);
                return questionList();
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Padding errorData(AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Error: ${snapshot.error}", 
            textAlign: TextAlign.center, 
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'product_sans',
              fontSize: 16.0, 
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              fetchQuestions();
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Text(
              "Try Again", 
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'product_sans', 
                fontSize: 16.0, 
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView questionList(){
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: results.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        child: ExpansionTile(
          title: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  results[index].question,

                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontFamily: 'product_sans',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),

                  ),
                  FittedBox(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FilterChip(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                          label: Text(results[index].category),
                          onSelected: (b) {},
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10.0,
                        ),
                        FilterChip(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                          label: Text(results[index].difficulty),
                          onSelected: (b) {},
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
            ),
          ),
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
            child: Text(results[index].type.startsWith("m") ? "M" : "B"),
          ),

          children: results[index].allAnswers.map((m){
            return AnswerWidget(results, index, m);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnswerWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Results> results;
  final int index;
  final String m;

  AnswerWidget(this.results, this.index, this.m);

  @override
  _AnswerWidgetState createState() => _AnswerWidgetState();
}

class _AnswerWidgetState extends State<AnswerWidget> {

  Color c = Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if(widget.m == widget.results[widget.index].correctAnswer){
          c = Colors.green;
        }
        else{
          c = Colors.red;
        }
        });
      },
      title: Text(
        widget.m,

        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'product_sans',
          color: c,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is an example of the output I get when I enter the link in Firefox:

```
response_code   0
results 
0   
category    "Science: Mathematics"
type    "multiple"
difficulty  "easy"
question    "How is the number 9 represented as a binary number?"
correct_answer  "1001"
incorrect_answers   
0   "1000"
1   "1110"
2   "1010"
1   
category    "Entertainment: Music"
type    "boolean"
difficulty  "medium"
question    "Rapper Snoop Dogg&#039;s real name is &#039;Cordozar Calvin Broadus, Jr.&#039;."
correct_answer  "True"
incorrect_answers   
0   "False"
2   
category    "Entertainment: Video Games"
type    "multiple"
difficulty  "easy"
question    "What is the protagonist&#039;s title given by the demons in DOOM (2016)?"
correct_answer  "Doom Slayer"
incorrect_answers   
0   "Doom Guy"
1   "Doom Marine"
2   "Doom Reaper"
3   
category    "Science: Computers"
type    "boolean"
difficulty  "hard"
question    "DHCP stands for Dynamic Host Configuration Port."
correct_answer  "False"
incorrect_answers   
0   "True"
4   
category    "Entertainment: Board Games"
type    "multiple"
difficulty  "hard"
question    "In standard Monopoly, what&#039;s the rent if you land on Park Place with no houses?"
correct_answer  "$35"
incorrect_answers   
0   "$30"
1   "$50"
2   "$45"
5   
category    "General Knowledge"
type    "multiple"
difficulty  "medium"
question    "When was Nintendo founded?"
correct_answer  "September 23rd, 1889"
incorrect_answers   
0   "October 19th, 1891"
1   "March 4th, 1887"
2   "December 27th, 1894"
6   
category    "General Knowledge"
type    "multiple"
difficulty  "medium"
question    "Which iconic Disneyland attraction was closed in 2017 to be remodeled as a &quot;Guardians of the Galaxy&quot; themed ride?"
correct_answer  "Twilight Zone Tower of Terror"
incorrect_answers   
0   "The Haunted Mansion"
1   "Pirates of the Caribbean"
2   "Peter Pan&#039;s Flight"
7   
category    "Entertainment: Video Games"
type    "multiple"
difficulty  "medium"
question    "What was the #1 selling game on Steam by revenue in 2016?"
correct_answer  "Sid Meier&#039;s Civilization VI"
incorrect_answers   
0   "Grand Theft Auto V"
1   "Counter Strike: Global Offensive"
2   "Dark Souls III"
8   
category    "Entertainment: Video Games"
type    "multiple"
difficulty  "easy"
question    "In &quot;Call Of Duty: Zombies&quot;, what is the name of the machine that upgrades weapons?"
correct_answer  "Pack-A-Punch"
incorrect_answers   
0   "Wunderfizz"
1   "Gersch Device"
2   "Mule Kick"
9   
category    "General Knowledge"
type    "multiple"
difficulty  "medium"
question    "Earl Grey tea is black tea flavoured with what?"
correct_answer  "Bergamot oil"
incorrect_answers   
0   "Lavender"
1   "Vanilla"
2   "Honey"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's a HTML encoded string. You can use [html_unescape](https://pub.dev/packages/html_unescape) flutter package to decode it and display it.